# How to remove an element from a .json file?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file: "data.json" containing a JSONArray of about 600 objects that have attributes: alias, telephone, type,  building and title. And I'm trying to remove all of the alias and telephone attributes from the objects in the array.

Here's a sample:

```
[
  {
    "Title": "7 Eleven",
    "Alias": "Seven Eleven",
    "Building": "7 Eleven"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Adaptive Computing Research Lab",
    "Alias": "acrl",
    "Type": "Faculty",
    "Building": "COM1"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Alcove.Asian Restaurant Bar",
    "Building": "University Cultural Centre"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Algorithms Research Lab",
    "Alias": "arl",
    "Type": "Faculty",
    "Building": "COM1"
  }
]
```

I understand that this is a JsonArray so I have to parse it is as a JsonArray type instead of a JsonObject so the parsing is not the problem. But when I use this code

```
import javax.json.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader("data.json"));
    JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) reader.read();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {

        JsonObject o = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);

        if (o.containsKey("Alias"))
            o.remove("Alias");

        if (o.containsKey("Telephone"))
            o.remove("Telephone");

        System.out.println(jsonArray);
    }

}
```

I'm having this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$1.remove(Collections.java:1664)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.remove(AbstractMap.java:254)
    at JSONEditor.main(JSONEditor.java:20)`

I don't understand why it is Unmodifiable.

So far, I've looked through many other similar questions and answers on StackOverflow and documentation that suggest that what I'm trying to do is possible but I still don't understand why this isn't working out for me.

Comment: JsonArray represents an immutable JSON array

Comment: @InjuredThePatient Oh!! So that's why. So you mean that if I still want to modify the .json file, I'll have to create a JSONArray and do the same operations on it instead? Or am I understanding Json and JSON wrong!

Comment: can I ask - why you want/need to use JavaEE here ?

Comment: @InjuredThePatient I recently just started using IntelliJ so I'm actually not sure of the differences between javaSE and JavaEE.

Comment: I understand, then you are not tied up to javaEE ? and we could use some other libraries ? :) and the goal is to remove the pair yes ?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: If you are going to use the solution I suggested is probably best to change the question as my answer does not answer it directly. Probably How to remove an element from JSON, or something like that, which possibly going to end up being a duplicate of something already.

Comment: please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers it's good to let other users know that your problem is solved/not solved by voting/marking answers.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. Thanks for the help, in the end, I chose to modify my JSON file using different libraries as it was ultimately easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This should help, its a widely known library `Jackson Databind` which you can use to work with your Json. below is the link to the library.
    https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.8.1

And here is the code that should help you.
Note that the file I have put into `src/main/resources`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Main main = new Main();
        File file = main.getFile("data.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(file);

        for (JsonNode jsonNode : root) {
            if (jsonNode instanceof ObjectNode) {
                ObjectNode o = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
                o.remove("Alias");
                o.remove("Telephone");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(root);    
    }

    private File getFile(String fileName) {
        return new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is built on your current code. This code builds a new JSONArray that only has the data you want to keep.

```
    try 
    {
        File file = new File("data.json");
        if(file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader("data.json"));
        JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) reader.read();

        JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
        //Build new json Array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {  
            String titleData = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Title") != null ? jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Title").toString() : "";            
            String buildingData = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Building") != null ? jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Building").toString() : "";              
            String typeData = jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Type") != null ? jsonArray.getJsonObject(i).get("Type").toString() : "";                                               
            JsonObject object = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("Title", titleData).add("Building", buildingData).add("Type", typeData).build();

            jsonArrayBuilder.add(object);               
        }

        JsonArray newJSONArray = jsonArrayBuilder.build();
        //print newJSONArray
        for(JsonValue jsonValue : newJSONArray)
        {
            System.out.println(jsonValue);
        }            
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This solution actually answers the posted question.

Comment: Not exactly the answer the OP was looking for. He wanted to *remove* two fields and your answer *keeps* three fields. If the JSON would have thousands of fields and you wanted to remove just one field this solution would be awful (imagine lines and lines of `.getJSONObject(i)...` and `.add(fieldName, value)`

Comment: His question is specific and so is this answer. Like it was said earlier, the JsonArray is an immutable object. You can not remove a value from it. Given this fact, you can create a new JsonArray containing only the elements you like. Like you pointed out, this answer would still work if scaled up, yet it will require more work. The key here being it will still works.

Comment: If you have a more efficient solution post it.

Comment: Totally agree with you, I have posted one using Jackson's databind.

Comment: Also, if he doesn't want the "Type" to be added always, he can adjust that part of the code. I am personally not a fan of JSON objects with slightly different structure all in the same JSONArray.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Sorry, there's one thing i don't understand about the answer you provided, which is the last error
'Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication44.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);'
what is JavaApplication44 ? and do I have to import another library for it?

Comment: `Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication44.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` is added automatically when I tell Netbeans to surround the block with try and catch. You can change it to `System.out.println(ex.toString());`